# How save service value in scope?

Tags: angularjs

---

Hi,
I'm trying to use service value (JSON) in controller and go to another view:

```
.controller('TrainCtrl', function ($scope, $sce, $state, medias) {

    $scope.train = function(id){
        medias.getMedias().then(function(message){
            $scope.movie = message.training;
            // Object {id: 1, title: ""...}
            console.log($scope.movie);
        });
        // undefined
        console.log($scope.movie);
        // View is empty because $scope.movie is undefined
        $state.go('training');
    };})

    .factory('medias', function($http, $log, $q){
    return{
        getMedias: function(){
            console.log('getMedias');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('js/medias.json')
            .success(function(data){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(msg, code){
                deferred.reject(msg);
                $log.error(msg,code)
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

How can I save result of the service to use in controller which redirect in directives ?

My Json :

```
{"training" :
{"id" : 1,
"url": "http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4",
"content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim",
"type": "video/mp4"
}
```

}

It doesnt work too :

```
$scope.train = function(id){
    medias.getMedias().then(function(message){
        //$scope.movie = message.training;
        $scope.movie={
        url: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"),
        content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
        type: 'video/mp4'
    };
        $state.go('training');
    });

};
```

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about asyncronicity...

```
$scope.train = function(id){

    medias.getMedias().then(function(message){
        //This is async callback
    });
    // ! This is normal execution, calling movie syncronously, movie is not yet defined !
    console.log($scope.movie);
    $state.go('training');
};})
```

the `.then` is called after the http get, it can be call at any time during the execution of your program. In order to work you should put everything in the `.then`

```
$scope.train = function(id){
    medias.getMedias().then(function(message){
        $scope.movie = message.training;
        // Object {id: 1, title: ""...}
        console.log($scope.movie);
        // undefined
        console.log($scope.movie);
        // View is empty because $scope.movie is undefined
        $state.go('training');
    });
};})
```

Angular will update the view acordingly.

Comment: Thanks but I did it and my view is still empty. It works only if I write $scope.movie={id: 1, title:"aaaa",...}; directly before $state.go. I dont understand where is my error.

Comment: What do you get when loging message ?

Comment: I see Object {id:1, title:"", ....} but directive is empty like if $scope.movie doesnt exists. If I add "$scope.movie={...}; $state.go();" after getMedias function, it works, of course.

Comment: I wanted to say message.training not message, are you sure training is not too much here ?

Comment: my JSON file contains {training:{id: .., title ...}. I tried to add directly into the code : $scope.movie={
            url: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/external/85569724.sd.mp4?s=43df5df0d733011263687d20a47557e4"),
            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor ',
            type: 'video/mp4'};   but it doesnt work too.